# Query to search array for nested matching / not-matching items?

Tags: elasticsearch-dsl

How can I write a DSL query to select documents having a JSON object in which field `configs_1.a_addr` does **not** match `configs_2.b_addr`, for all objects in the array `xxx`?

```
{
  "name": "steve_doc_45",
  "xxx": [
    {
      "name": "s1",
      "configs_1": {
        "a_addr": "10.1.2.3",
        "a_mask": "255.255.224.0"
      },
      "configs_2": {
        "b_addr": "10.1.2.3",
        "b_mask": "255.255.224.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "s2",
      "configs_1": {
        "a_addr": "10.5.5.5",
        "a_mask": "255.255.224.0"
      },
      "configs_2": {
        "b_addr": "10.6.6.6",
        "b_mask": "255.255.224.0"
      }
    }
  ],
  "other": "stuff"
}
```

In this example, the doc **should** match because in the object with name `s2`, value `10.5.5.5` does **not** match `10.6.6.6`.

If this object is deleted from array `xxx`, then this doc should **not** match the DSL query because the object with name `s1` **does** have matching fields, and it's then the only object in the array `xxx`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) query for this.

**Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "xxx",
          "query": {
            "script": {
              "script": """
                    if (doc['xxx.configs_1.a_addr.keyword'].value != doc['xxx.configs_2.b_addr.keyword'].value) 
                    {
                      return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                    """
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**

In nested type every object of array is treated as a separate document i.e. relationship between fields is maintained.

In case of object types multiple instances of a field are flattened
as an unordered array.

Please test carefully, doc[] only stores unique values. if names are not unique loop will only run once and skip second object.

```
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": """
                   for(int i=0; i<doc['xxx.name.keyword'].length; i++)
                   {
                      if (doc['xxx.configs_1.a_addr.keyword'][i] != doc['xxx.configs_2.b_addr.keyword'][i]) 
                      {
                        return true;
                      }  
                   }
                   return false;
"""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That fails to work: `[nested] nested object under path [xxx] is not of nested type` My data is ingested raw, without explicit mappings. If I simply use the script above without `nested`, the error becomes `No field found for [xxx] in mapping with types []`. This is Elasticsearch **7.5.2**, which I think does not have **runtime fields**. Any tips how to proceed?

Comment: The problem still remains -- regardless of Elasticsearch flattening nuances, your suggested search directives fail immediately on "raw ingested" data, which is uploaded into Elasticsearch without explicit mapping directives.

Comment: `"reason": "No field found for [xxx.name.keyword] in mapping with types []`

Comment: I guess I'd like to "cast" this array dynamically into something usable without re-indexing. Descriptions of "runtime fields" and "scripted fields" might be a way forward, but I'm not familiar with using them. Another approach might be casting each sub-array into a string and diff'ing; that may or may not be effective with my data. Of course I could simply do mass downloads with some other criteria and process this coventionally client-side, but that's a huge data transfer and somewhat defeats the purpose of "search" in Elasticsearch.

Comment: @JohnDB can you add your mapping. you can get by Get <index>/_mapping

Comment: Here's the relevant extract. (Use **jq** to expand)
`{"mappings":{"properties":{"xxx":{"properties":{"name":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"configs_1":{"properties":{"a_addr":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"a_mask":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}},"configs_2":{"properties":{"b_addr":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"b_mask":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}}}}}}}`

Comment: {
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": """
                   if (!(doc['xxx.name.keyword'] instanceof List))
                   {
                     return false;
                   }
                   
                   for(int i=0; i<doc['xxx.name.keyword'].length; i++)
                   {
                      if (doc['xxx.configs_1.a_addr.keyword'][i] != doc['xxx.configs_2.b_addr.keyword'][i]) 
                      {
                        return true;
                      }  
                   }
                   return false;
"""
    }  } } chk this

Comment: I **do** appreciate your tips! But I still get the same error:
```"if (!(doc['xxx.name.keyword'] instanceof List)) { ",
"          ^---- HERE"
"reason": "runtime error",
"caused_by": {
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "No field found for [xxx.name.keyword] in mapping with types []" ```
 
Maybe I can dynamically add something into the type[] array?
But I'm not sure how, or if this is perhaps the limit of "no explicit mappings". (Horrible formatting, not sure how to fix it this inline mode.)

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to resolve this issue directly. In the medium to long-term, I intend to (1) upgrade Elasticsearch to a newer version, and (2) refactor the indexes to use explicit mappings, so I can make use of the great suggestions from @JaspreetChahal.

Meanwhile, in the short-term, I patched the data-source uploader to explicitly check for this condition and add a comment into a messages field (array of strings) which I can then search for directly with a DSL Query String Query - also with wildcards. This works.